# Problems with opentype options under XeTeX

Tags: xetex, linux, libertine

I am new in the LaTeX world, so I don't understand everything about it, especially about the use of fonts.

I installed Linux Libertine font on my distribution (I use Gentoo, so I installed the package `media-fonts/libertine-ttf`), and it works fine using WYSIWYG programs, like LibreOffice. I can use the `Linux Libertine O`, `Linux Libertine O C` etc.

But, using XeTeX, it doesn't work. I set in my header

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Contextual, Common, Historical, Rare, Discretionary}]{Linux Libertine O}
```

But when I compile with `xelatex`, it says

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)kpathsea: Invalid fontname `Linux Libertine O', contains ' '


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! 
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H .
!...............................................
```

When I remove the `O` in `Linux Libertine O`, it says:

```
 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/B',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/B',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/I',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/I',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Contextual' (+clig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/BI',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Historical' (+hlig) not availabl
e
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/BI',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.

 fontspec warning: OpenType feature 'Letters=SmallCaps' (+smcp) not available
(fontspec)  for font 'Linux Libertine/BI',
(fontspec)  with script 'Latin', and language 'Default'.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertine(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 26.
```

What is wrong with my code (shown below)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{lettre}

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

%\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures=Historical]{Linux Libertine}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Contextual, Common, Historical, Rare, Discretionary}]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Régie Trouduc'\\42, rue de tes fesses\\69007 Lyon}
\name{Lenny Baralair}
\address{Georges Dupont\\42, rue du chariot d'or\\69001 Lyon\\
        {\addfontfeature{Letters=SmallCaps} Numéro de référence locataire : 654654654} }
\lieu{Paris}
\telephone{06 42 42 42 42}
\nofax

\conc{pouet}

\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}

Ceci est ma lettre que je ne veux pas rendre public sur ce site.

\closing{Je vous prie d'agréer,
Madame, Monsieur,
l'expression de mes salutations distinguées.}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should never use `babel` with XeLaTeX. Use [Polyglossia](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead.

Comment: @Andrey as a one-time dispenser of such advice too, I discovered that it's a bit more complicated than that.  French, however maybe one of those languages where the advice is well taken, although the french in babel is does much much more than the french in polyglossia.  See [Polyglossia, babel and xelatex](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2011-May/020493.html)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Thanks. I will now be more careful with such statements. Needless to say that I don't like the current situation with internationalization at all. `babel` can't work in many cases because it knows little, if nothing, about Unicode, and `polyglossia` is a reimplementation, rather than extension, of `babel`, and often can do less (and the code quality may be worse than that of `babel`, IMHO). And it's complicated for LuaLaTeX users, too. It would be a lot better if there was a consolidated effort to produce a package that works for all languages and on all engines.

Comment: @Andrey Yes, I agree on all counts. (No comment on the code quality.) But polyglossia was developed before LuaTeX was really viable, and because it uses `xetexintercharclass` it's incompatible, IIRC.

Comment: @Andrey: I use `babel`'s `frenchb` with both XeTeX and LuaTeX without a problem, and I've heard polyglossia does a poorer job with French.

Comment: @doncherry: Ok, I'll remove it then.

Answer (score 13):

First, a font does not necessarily support all types of ligatures. Linux Libertine supports only (checked here) `Ligatures={Common,Rare,Discretionary}`.

The OpenType variant of Linux Libertine shipped with `media-fonts/libertine-ttf` works on an up-to-date Gentoo with TeX Live 2011. Another option is to install the `dev-texlive/texlive-fontsextra` package, which also contains the font. To use it and to be able to select it by name, run this command after installation:

```
eselect fontconfig enable 09-texlive.conf
```

This will allow all programs to access fonts installed in the TeX Live `texmf` tree.

Then this code will work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common,Rare,Discretionary}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

*Note: This was tested on TeX Live 2011. Gentoo has TeX Live 2010 as the stable version. If you keep experiencing problems, try upgrading to the newer version of TeX Live.*

Comment: @DaveNull: if this answers your question, please check the answer.